# Akrabat zf2TestApp issue

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I an a zend beginner and recently came across the ZF2Testapp.I downloaded Akrabat's test app,replaced my skelton app with it and ran into this error

```
Warning: require_once(vendor/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Loader/AutoloaderFactory.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\Jobs\public\index.php on line 3

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'vendor/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Loader/AutoloaderFactory.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\Jobs\public\index.php on line 3
```

i tried commenting out this line in index.php and replacing it with     require 'init_autoloader.php' but it won't work

What could i be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have Zend Framework installed. My first guess is that you should install [Composer](http://getcomposer.org) and then run `composer install`